# Cloud9 IDE serves old version of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I started a simple project with an HTML and a Java Script file. I ran the html file and everything was fine. I continued with the workspace on another machine and found that I could not see any changes I made to the html or js files when I refresh the browser panel in c9 IDE. It seems to keep serving a previous (cached?) version of the files. Restarting the run configuration (apache) did not make any difference.

How can I get the c9 IDE to run the latest files again?

Comment: im sorry for the question, but, did you remember to save your project? ...

Comment: Maybe this will help http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20870547-Some-functionalities-of-Cloud9-IDE-are-not-working-what-can-I-do-

Comment: I saved the individual files with Ctrl+S but I noticed that "Save All" was still available in the menu. I clicked "Save All" and now it seems to work.

Comment: Got stuck again. This time "Save All" does not change anything.

Comment: Yep. Happens here as well.

Comment: I work at Cloud9. We used to have some caching enabled but this should be fixed now. If it still happens for anyone please let us know at http://community.c9.io and we'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome? I had the same issue, I looked up and it was Chrome's fault. Started using the extension [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap/related?hl=en) and that solved my problem.